# Newsletter subscribed but no confirmation mail

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email, newsletter

If I subscribe to the newsletter as guest I get a email to confirm my subscribtion but after I confirm I don't get a confirmation mail that I am subscribed now.

How can I change this to get the confirmation mail?

[image]

Comment: If it's just one mail that's not sending check for HTML syntax issues, optionally use the default email template. EDIT: check this post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/237771/

Comment: @SanderMangel If I subscribe as registered user I get this email so I think the template is fine. It is just not send if I subscribe as guest.

Comment: Did you check the link? I think this guy had the same issue (and solution)

Comment: @SanderMangel No, stupid me did not check the link. This was the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Sander Mangel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50/sander-mangel) pointed [out](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7830/newsletter-subscribed-but-no-confirmation-mail?noredirect=1#comment10662_7830) the solution is in `app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`. Copy this file to `app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`

Find `function confirm($code)` (Line 470 in CE-1.7.0.2) and add `$this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();`

Now the function should look like this:

```
public function confirm($code)
{
    if($this->getCode()==$code) {
        $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
            ->setIsStatusChanged(true)
            ->save();
        // This is new:
        $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```